# Use Microsoft Translator API to translate a whole web page with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-translator

translate a web page with Microsoft Translator API (SOAP) with C#. I want to make my websites translated, but using the Translator Widget is not good for me as I need google to crawl my translated pages as well. So I'll need to translate it before sending it to the browser.

So far there's no API (I tried finding it, I couldn't, If you happen to know one please mention) where you could just pass a url and it'll send you the translated response like this : http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=nl&a=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2F

These are the attempts I've taken so far:
1. Download string from Url, pass to Client.Translate(..).

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'Translate'. The maximum string content length quota (30720) has been
>   exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by
>   changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.
>   Line 516, position 48.

2.

```
private static void processDocument(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html, LanguageServiceClient Client)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection coll = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']");
            foreach (HtmlNode node in coll)
            {
                if (node.InnerText == node.InnerHtml)
                {
                    //node.InnerHtml = translateText(node.InnerText);
                    node.InnerHtml = Client.Translate("", node.InnerText, "en", "fr", "text/html", "general");
                }
            }

        }
```

This one this taking way too much time. And in the end I'm getting a Bad request (400) exception.

What would be the best way to tackle this problem? I also plan to save the documents so that I don't have to translate every time.

Answer (score 1):

This C# example translates HTML from a local file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace TranslationAssistant.Business
{
class HTMLTranslationManager
{
    public static int DoTranslation(string htmlfilename, string fromlanguage, string tolanguage)
    {
        string htmldocument = File.ReadAllText(htmlfilename);
        string htmlout = string.Empty;

        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmldocument);
        htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SetAttributeValue("lang", TranslationServices.Core.TranslationServiceFacade.LanguageNameToLanguageCode(tolanguage));
        var title = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head//title");
        if (title != null) title.InnerHtml = TranslationServices.Core.TranslationServiceFacade.TranslateString(title.InnerHtml, fromlanguage, tolanguage, "text/html");
        var body = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        if (body != null)
        {
            if (body.InnerHtml.Length < 10000)
            {
                body.InnerHtml = TranslationServices.Core.TranslationServiceFacade.TranslateString(body.InnerHtml, fromlanguage, tolanguage, "text/html");
            }
            else
            {
                List<HtmlNode> nodes = new List<HtmlNode>();
                AddNodes(body.FirstChild, ref nodes);

                Parallel.ForEach(nodes, (node) =>
                    {
                        if (node.InnerHtml.Length > 10000)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Child node with a length of more than 10000 characters encountered.");
                        }
                        node.InnerHtml = TranslationServices.Core.TranslationServiceFacade.TranslateString(node.InnerHtml, fromlanguage, tolanguage, "text/html");
                    });
            }
        }
        htmlDoc.Save(htmlfilename, Encoding.UTF8);
        return 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add nodes of size smaller than 10000 characters to the list, and recurse into the bigger ones.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootnode">The node to start from</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">Reference to the node list</param>
    private static void AddNodes(HtmlNode rootnode, ref List<HtmlNode> nodes)
    {
        string[] DNTList = { "script", "#text", "code", "col", "colgroup", "embed", "em", "#comment", "image", "map", "media", "meta", "source", "xml"};  //DNT - Do Not Translate - these nodes are skipped.
        HtmlNode child = rootnode;
        while (child != rootnode.LastChild)
        {
            if (!DNTList.Contains(child.Name.ToLowerInvariant())) {
                if (child.InnerHtml.Length > 10000)
                {
                    AddNodes(child.FirstChild, ref nodes);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (child.InnerHtml.Trim().Length != 0) nodes.Add(child);
                }
            }
            child = child.NextSibling;
        }
    }

}
}
```

This is HTMLTranslationManager.cs in  http://github.com/microsofttranslator/documenttranslator, and it uses the helper function TranslateString() in TranslationServiceFacade.cs. You could simplify and just insert the translation service call right here in place of TranslateString().